# Is there an equivalent property of Similar Matrices for rectangular matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Say I have the following:

$Z = A^T B A$

where $Z$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, $B$ is an $m \times m$ matrix, and $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix, $n<m$.

Furthermore, the columns of $A$ are orthogonal, and $B$ is a positive definite matrix and $Z$ is symmetric tridiagonal.

This bears similarities to two similar $m\times m$ matrices, $X$ and $Y$, requiring Y = $P^{-1}XP$ for some invertible matrix $P$.

Obviously in my case, $B$ and $Z$ don't have the same dimensions, and as $A$ is a truncated orthogonal matrix, it only has the property $A^TA=I$ (and not the other way round).

However, can any properties of similar matrices follow from this, such as the characteristic polynomial, determinant or eigenvalues?

Answer (score 1):

Extend $A$ to an orthogonal matrix $Q=\pmatrix{A&\ast}$. Then $Z$ is the leading principal $n\times n$ submatrix of $Q^TBQ$. Therefore $Z$ is positive definite and by Cauchy interlacing inequality, the $i$-th smallest eigenvalue of $Z$ is bounded below by the $i$-th smallest eigenvalue of $B$.